# Cannot access localstorage from sveltekit hook

Tags: javascript, local-storage, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I've got a function that verifies whether an user is logged in or not:

```
export const isUserLoggedIn = () => {

    let dmcAuthToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);

    return dmcAuthToken ? true : false;

}
```

when an user logs in, local storage is updated with a token returned from the backend:

```
localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, dmcAuthToken);
```

Now, I'm trying to restrict access to pages when the user is not logged, I've read a bit and found a hook called `handle` so I decided to implement this logic there:

`/src/hooks.js`:

```
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {

    if (!isUserLoggedIn() && event.url.pathname != "/login") {
        console.log("user NOT logged in");
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 302,
            headers: {
                location: "/login"
            }
        })
    }

    if (isUserLoggedIn() && event.url.pathname == "/login") {
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 302,
            headers: {
                location: "/pos"
            }
        })
    }

    return resolve(event);
}
```

But I'm getting an error:
`500 localStorage is not defined`

any idea what's going on?

For testing, if I return either `true` or `false` from `isUserLoggedIn` the implemented logic in the hook seems to work, but the issue is when trying to access `localStorage`, why is that?

I've seen solution where the token is saved in a store but don't wanna go that route unless it's necessary, I'd like to know why my way isn't working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `localStorage` is not available on the server side

please use `cookie` to save token

Comment: so that's something i tried. In the file where `isUserLoggedIn` is declared I imported `import cookie from 'cookie';` then within `isUserLoggedIn` I did (for testing):
`cookie.set("AUTH_TOKEN_KEY", "this is a test cookie...")` but then I got a different error: `__vite_ssr_import_2__.default.set is not a function`

Comment: package `npm:cookie` is a package dedicated to parse set-cookie server side you must use mixed cookie please use [npm:js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie)  if still having trouble tell me i will include example in the answer

Comment: of course if you don't like packages you can use primitive api

Comment: so i tried using `js-cookie` but still not working as expected. I mean, even using `js-cookie` we'd be in the same situation. Cookies are set in the client, and the hook as being pointed by you, it's being running server-side so it wouldn't have access to the cookie

Comment: okay you don't seem to understand what I mean. Cookies are allowed both on client and server in svelte hook you can use `cookies` to access it easily https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#cookies-and-headers

Answer (score 0):

Probably because hook runs on server side. Try adding `!browser` to check. Or `typeof window !== 'undefined'`

Comment: I saw the `browser` directive from `$app/environment` but then again, this is false when the hook checks and I need to access `localStorage` so adding it within a check for `browser` is will get rid of the error but wouldn't be a solution for me

Comment: @MrCujo, you need to use cookies; it's the only way to check authorization with SSR. And you'll probably gain more headaches instead of benefits.